# generalized aggregate by row

Tags: r, aggregate

I would like to aggregate by row.  I know how to do this and have answered several questions here from others asking for help doing it.  However, I want to generalize the aggregate formula and ideally not have the aggregated rows in a different order than they first appear in the original data set.

Here is an example set:

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '
    0 0 0 1
    0 0 0 1
    2 2 2 2
    2 2 2 2
    0 4 0 0
    0 4 0 0
    2 2 0 0
    2 2 0 0
    2 2 0 0
    2 2 0 0
', header = FALSE)
```

and my desired result:

```
desired.result <- read.table(text = '
    0 0 0 1 2
    2 2 2 2 2
    0 4 0 0 2
    2 2 0 0 4
', header = FALSE)
```

Here is one way to obtain the answer, albeit the rows are not in their original order:

```
my.data[,(ncol(my.data)+1)] = 1

aggregate(V5 ~ V1 + V2 + V3 + V4, FUN = sum, data=my.data)

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1  2  2  0  0  4
2  0  4  0  0  2
3  0  0  0  1  2
4  2  2  2  2  2
```

Here is an unsuccessful attempt to generalize the aggregate formula:

```
with(my.data, aggregate(my.data[,ncol(my.data)], by = list(paste0('V', seq(1, ncol(my.data)-1))), FUN = sum))
```

The order of the result is less important than the generalization.

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: When you say "generalize", you mean something like `aggregate(V5 ~ ., my.data, sum)`?

Comment: @alexis_laz I am not sure what you mean.  Your code does not run.  I have provided the desired result.  Please let me know how I can clarify.  Also, V5 is not generalized.  It would only apply if there were five columns.

Comment: Sorry, I took "V5" as granted in your example dataset. If you're just looking for frequency counts of rows, then you could use `table` instead of `aggregate`? Or is it just a simplified problem? E.g. `tmp = do.call(paste, my.data); data.frame(unique(my.data), unclass(table(factor(tmp, unique(tmp)))))`

Comment: @alexis_laz  Thank you.  That code does the task.  It also keeps the rows in the same order as they first appear in the original data set.  Please consider posting your code as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it turned out that the desired result is just the frequency counts of unique rows, you could/should use `table` (as mentioned in the comments). `table` uses `factor` on its arguments and `factor`, if "levels" is not specified, `sort`s its input's `unique` (`unique` does not sort) to specify the levels. So, for `table` to "see" your levels (i.e. the desired order of rows) you need to call `table` on an explicitly specified `factor`.

```
tmp = do.call(paste, my.data)
as.data.frame(table(tmp))
#      tmp Freq
#1 0 0 0 1    2
#2 0 4 0 0    2
#3 2 2 0 0    4
#4 2 2 2 2    2    
res = table(factor(tmp, unique(tmp)))
as.data.frame(res)
#     Var1 Freq
#1 0 0 0 1    2
#2 2 2 2 2    2
#3 0 4 0 0    2
#4 2 2 0 0    4
```

Instead of calling `as.data.frame.table` -where your rows have been concatenated- you could take advantage of `unique.data.frame` and use a call like:

```
data.frame(unique(my.data), unclass(res))
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 unclass.res.
#1  0  0  0  1            2
#3  2  2  2  2            2
#5  0  4  0  0            2
#7  2  2  0  0            4
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be useful to mention that the `count` function in the `plyr` package can also aggregate this quickly. Although, you still would lose the original order of rows.

```
> library(plyr)
> x <- count(my.data)
> x
##   V1 V2 V3 V4 freq
## 1  0  0  0  1    2
## 2  0  4  0  0    2
## 3  2  2  0  0    4
## 4  2  2  2  2    2
```

To order the table as `desired.result` shows (and borrowing a snippet from @alexis_laz),

```
> pst <- do.call(paste, my.data)
> x[order(x$freq, as.factor(unique(pst))), ]
##   V1 V2 V3 V4 freq
## 1  0  0  0  1    2
## 4  2  2  2  2    2
## 2  0  4  0  0    2
## 3  2  2  0  0    4
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the posted answers, especially the answer by @alexis_laz since I tend to prefer base `R`.  However, here is a general answer using `aggregate`.  The order of the rows in the output differs from the order of their first appearance in the original data set, but at least the rows are tallied:

I borrowed the `.` in `aggregate` from @alexis_laz's comment:

```
my.data <- read.table(text = '

    0 0 0 1
    0 0 0 1
    2 2 2 2
    2 2 2 2
    0 4 0 0
    0 4 0 0
    2 2 0 0
    2 2 0 0
    2 2 0 0
    2 2 0 0

', header = FALSE)

my.data

my.count = rep(1, nrow(my.data))
my.count

aggregate(my.count ~ ., FUN = sum, data=my.data)

  V1 V2 V3 V4 my.count
1  2  2  0  0        4
2  0  4  0  0        2
3  0  0  0  1        2
4  2  2  2  2        2
```